# XMLHttpRequest has no connection to the localhost if internet turnes off (Qt 5.6-5.7, QML)

Tags: javascript, qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

XMLHttpRequest has no connection to the localhost if internet turnes off (Qt 5.6-5.7, QML)

**Description of the environment:**
PC with a local server: valid request this server returns some text;

**My Network configuration:**
    Ethernet adapter

**Tested on PC:**
    Win 10 64bit,
    Win 10 32bit.

**Tested compilers:**
    Qt 5.6.0 msvc 2013 32bit,
    Qt 5.6.1 msvc 2013 32bit,
    Qt 5.6.1 msvc 2013 64bit,
    Qt 5.7.0 msvc 2013 64bit,
    Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32bit.

**My code example:**
*Client sample*

```
/*project.pro*/
    TEMPLATE = app

    QT += qml quick

    CONFIG += c++11

    SOURCES += main.cpp

    RESOURCES += qml.qrc

    # Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
    QML_IMPORT_PATH =

    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


/*main.cpp*/
    #include <QGuiApplication>
    #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

        return app.exec();
    }

/*main.qml*/
    import QtQuick 2.4
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    Window {
        id: root
        visible: true

        property int it: 0

        Timer {
            id: timer;
            interval: 5000;
            repeat: true;
            onTriggered: {
                root.it++;
                sendCommand(root.it);
            }

            Component.onCompleted: timer.start();
        }

        function sendCommand(iteration) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            timer.running = false;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                timer.running = true;
                console.debug("Iteration %1: request.readyState = %2, request.responseText: '%3'"
                              .arg(iteration)
                              .arg(getReqState(request))
                              .arg(request.responseText.toString()));
            }
            request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:33333/', false);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function getReqState(request) {
            switch(request.readyState) {
            case XMLHttpRequest.OPENED:
                return "OPENED";
            case XMLHttpRequest.LOADING:
                return "LOADING";
            case XMLHttpRequest.HEADERS_RECEIVED:
                return "HEADERS_RECEIVED";
            case XMLHttpRequest.DONE:
                return "DONE";
            }
        }
    }
```

*Server sample*

```
/*server.pro*/
    QT       += core gui network
    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
    TARGET = untitled6
    TEMPLATE = app
    SOURCES += main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp
    HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
    FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

/*main.cpp*/
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }

/*mainwindow.h*/
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QtNetwork>
    #include <QTcpSocket>
    #include <QObject>
    #include <QByteArray>
    #include <QDebug>

    namespace Ui {
        class MainWindow;
    }

    class QTcpServer;

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    private slots:
        void on_starting_clicked();
        void on_stoping_clicked();
        void newuser();
        void slotReadClient();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QTcpServer *tcpServer;
        int server_status;
        QMap<int,QTcpSocket *> SClients;
    };
    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H

/*mainwindow.cpp*/
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }

    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
        server_status=0;
    }

    void MainWindow::on_starting_clicked()
    {
        tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
        connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newuser()));
        if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 33333) && server_status==0) {
            qDebug() <<  QObject::tr("Unable to start the server: %1.").arg(tcpServer->errorString());
            ui->textinfo->append(tcpServer->errorString());
        } else {
            server_status=1;
            qDebug() << tcpServer->isListening() << "TCPSocket listen on port";
            ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("Server started!"));
            qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("Server started!");
        }
    }

    void MainWindow::on_stoping_clicked()
    {
        if(server_status==1){
            foreach(int i,SClients.keys()){
                QTextStream os(SClients[i]);
                os.setAutoDetectUnicode(true);
                os << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() << "\n";
                SClients[i]->close();
                SClients.remove(i);
            }
            tcpServer->close();
            ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("Server stopped!"));
            qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("Server stopped!");
            server_status=0;
        }
    }

    void MainWindow::newuser()
    {
        if(server_status==1){
            qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("New connection!");
            ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("New connection!"));
            QTcpSocket* clientSocket=tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
            int idusersocs=clientSocket->socketDescriptor();
            SClients[idusersocs]=clientSocket;
            connect(SClients[idusersocs],SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(slotReadClient()));
        }
    }

    void MainWindow::slotReadClient()
    {
        QTcpSocket* clientSocket = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
        int idusersocs=clientSocket->socketDescriptor();
        QTextStream os(clientSocket);
        os.setAutoDetectUnicode(true);
        os << "HTTP/1.0 200 Ok\r\n"
              "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n"
              "\r\n"
              "<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>"
              << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString();
        ui->textinfo->append("ReadClient:"+clientSocket->readAll()+"\n\r");

        clientSocket->close();
        SClients.remove(idusersocs);
    }

/*mainwindow.ui*/
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui version="4.0">
     <class>MainWindow</class>
     <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>796</width>
        <height>484</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="windowTitle">
       <string>MainWindow</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
        <item row="0" column="0" colspan="3">
         <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="textinfo"/>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="0">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="stoping">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Stop</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="1">
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>653</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
        <item row="1" column="2">
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="starting">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Start</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
     <resources/>
     <connections/>
    </ui>
```

*Problem description:*
1) When you run the application *with the connected Internet*, you get a response from the local server:

```
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
...
```

2) When you run the application *without Internet connection*, you get a response from the local server:

```
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
...
```

3) If you run an application with an Internet connection and turn it off after a 4 iterations you get:

```
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 1: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:31 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
qml: Iteration 2: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:36 2016'
qml: Iteration 3: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 3: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 3: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:41 2016'
qml: Iteration 3: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:41 2016'
qml: Iteration 4: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 4: request.readyState = HEADERS_RECEIVED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 4: request.readyState = LOADING, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:46 2016'
qml: Iteration 4: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: '<h1>Nothing to see here</h1>?? ??? 27 15:59:46 2016'
qml: Iteration 5: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 5: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 6: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 6: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 7: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 7: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 8: request.readyState = OPENED, request.responseText: ''
qml: Iteration 8: request.readyState = DONE, request.responseText: ''
...
```

After turning off Internet, access to local server possible via browser.
If you run in parallel with the first to the second instance of the application after disabling Internet. He (second instance) will receive a response from the local server.

**Why is there connection lost to the local server if internet is disabled?**
Who knows how to solve this problem?

upd: added Qt bug report https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56763

Comment: For this to make any sense, can you amend your program's output to show the `readyState` or `state` member of the request on each callback?

Comment: Can you connect to the local webserver when you internet connection is off, for example with your browser? What is your OS? What is a webserver you run? Is it possible that WS runs on non-local interface?

Comment: @folibis After turning off Internet, access to local server possible via browser.
If you run in parallel with the first to the second instance of the application after disabling Internet. He (second instance) will receive a response from the local server.